# Unity texture2d getPixel return wrong color

Tags: image, unity-game-engine, png, pixel, texture2d

I'm loading png as a texture:

```
 byte[] bytes = File.ReadAllBytes(path);
 Texture2D texture = new Texture2D(1, 1);
 texture.LoadImage(bytes);
```

The problem is with the pixel retrieved by `texture.GetPixel(23,23)`

In debug it seems to be white, debug log: `texture.GetPixel(23, 23) "RGBA(1.000, 1.000, 1.000, 0.000)"  UnityEngine.Color`

But it should be a kind of blue according to what I see in image:
[image]

I have no ideea how can I get the right value of this pixel.
I put here photos with textures, and what I obtained drawing from pixel colors
[image]

[image]

Code used:

```
public void JustTest()
{
    ClearGrid();
    byte[] bytes = File.ReadAllBytes(path);
    Texture2D texture = new Texture2D(1, 1);
    texture.LoadImage(bytes);
    for (int i = 0; i <= texture.width; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j <= texture.height; j++)
        {
            GameObject sa = Instantiate(_testTilePrefab, new Vector3(i, 0.2f, j), _testTilePrefab.transform.rotation);
            sa.GetComponent<Renderer>().material.color = texture.GetPixel(i, j);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's likely that Y axis index issue.
It could be top-bottom, bottom-top flip issue.

Edit:
You are missing “texture.Apply()” after loading the byte[]. Without the apply function, Your texture is still in white color by default.

```
texture.Apply();
```

Comment: Hi, is not that the case, i will edit my question to see exactly.

Comment: You are missing “texture.Apply()” after loading the byte[]. Without the apply function, Your texture is still in white color by default.

Answer (score -1):

The issue is very likely that texture get reduced in their resolution according to what you have configured in the bottom section of the [Texture Import Settings](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-TextureImporter.html) -> [Platform specific overrides -> MaxSize](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-TextureImporter.html#platform)

> Set the maximum imported Texture dimensions in pixels
> . Artists often prefer to work with huge dimension-size Textures, but you can scale down the Texture to a suitable dimension-size.

For your tile scene I'm almost sure that your tiles are too big and overlapping each other and thus the strange looking image.